# How to determine the sign of the eigenvalues of this $3\times3$ symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the symmetric matrix 
$$R=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
-(P+\lambda) & P & 0 \\
P & -(P+Q) & Q \\
0 & Q & -(Q+\mu)
\end{array}
\right)$$

We know that $P,Q,\lambda$ and $\mu$ are $>0$. I'm a little rusty on my LA, are there any applicable theorems here to give information on the eigenvalues? In particular their sign.

Comment: Are $P,Q,\lambda,\mu$ all real numbers, or are they block matrices?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom all real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Gershgorin disc theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem), $R$ has at least two negative eigenvalues and the third one is nonpositive. Since
\begin{align*}
\det(R)
&=-(P+\lambda)(P+Q)(Q+\mu)+(P+\lambda)Q^2+(Q+\mu)P^2\\
&=-P Q \lambda-P Q \mu - P \lambda \mu - Q \lambda \mu\\
&<0,
\end{align*}
the third eigenvalue is also negative.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $P,Q,\lambda,\mu \in \Bbb R$: note that your matrix is [diagonally dominant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix) with negative diagonal entries, or apply the [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem).

By either approach, we may deduce that the eigenvalues of $R$ are all $\leq 0$.  I don't believe that we necessarily know, however, if $R$ is invertible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, both your answer and user1551's were exactly what I needed.

Comment: To get rid of the possibility of the eigenvalue zero, solve $RX=0$.